# Is there a way to express the basis for $\hom(V,W)$ abstractly?

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

Suppose:

- $V$ and $W$ are two finite-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$
- $\dim(V)=n$, $\dim(W)=m$
- $\mathcal{E}=\{e_i\}_1^n\in V^n$ is an ordered basis for $V$
- $e_i^*:V\to\mathbb{R}$ is the $i$-th coordinate functional with regard to $\mathcal{E}$, thus $\forall v\in V,\ v=\sum_i^n e_i^*(v)\cdot e_i$
- $\mathcal{E}^*=\{e_i^*\}_1^n$ is the dual basis for $V^*$ (the dual space of $V$).

I feel it's difficult to grasp the concept of dual basis, although $\forall f\in \hom(V,\mathbb{R})$, the following identity suggests so:

$$f(v)=f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n e_i^*(v)\cdot e_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n e_i^*(v)\cdot f(e_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n f(e_i)\cdot e_i^*(v)$$

In the identity above, the change of the order of $e_i^*(v)$ and $f(e_i)$ is interesting.

For $\tau\in\hom(V,W)$, we have a similar identity, wrt $\mathcal{E}$:

$$\tau(v)=\tau\left(\sum_{i=1}^n e_i^*(v)\cdot e_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n e_i^*(v)\cdot \tau(e_i)$$
But I don't know if there is also a meaningful interpretation if the order of the two terms are swapped:

$$\tau(v)=\sum_{i=1}^n \tau(e_i)\cdot e_i^*(v)$$
It seems that the skeleton of $f$, i.e., $\{f(e_i)\}_1^n$ *happen* to be in $\mathbb{R}$, thus they can treated as coefficients (so the change of order); but the skeleton of $\tau$, i.e., $\{\tau(e_i)\}_1^n$ are in $W$, probably that's why they can not be treated as coefficients?

In any case, from either $\tau(v)=\sum \tau(e_i)\cdot e_i^*(v)\ \ $ or $\ \ \tau(v)=\sum e_i^*(v)\cdot \tau(e_i)$, it's not obvious to see that $\tau$ is a linear combination of a basis in $\hom(V,W)$, as the dimension of $\hom(V,W)$ is $m\times n$ while the sum only goes from $1$ to $n$. So my question is, is there a way to express $\tau$ as the linear combination of a basis in $\hom(V,W)$, similar to what we see for the linear functional $f\in \hom(V,\mathbb{R})$?

Thanks,

/bruin

Comment: $e_i^*(v)$ is a scalar. In a vector space you can multiply from left and from right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I think I have a kind of understanding for the order change, under the assumption that there is a convention to put coefficients before basis elements. Consider the general case $\tau:V\to W$, for $\tau=\sum\tau(e_i)\cdot e_i^*$, once the basis $\mathcal{E}$ for $V$ is chosen, $e_i$ and $e_i^*$ are fixed/settled/known, what's unsettled/unknown for $\tau\in\hom(V,W)$ is how $\tau$ acts on $\mathcal{E}$, i.e, the skeleton of $\tau$. So from this view point, it's natural to treat the skeleton as the coefficients, thus the change of order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a basis $\mathcal{F}=\{f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_m\}$ of $W$. Then, for each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, $\tau(e_i)$ can be written as $\sum_{j=1}^ma_{ij}f_j$. Therefore\begin{align}\tau(v)&=\sum_{i=1}^ne_i^*(v)\tau(e_i)\\&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^ma_{ij}e_i^*(v)f_j.\end{align}You can deduce from this that the elements of $\hom(V,W)$ of the form $v\mapsto e_i^*(v)f_j$ form a basis of $\hom(V,W)$.

Comment: Probably a typo for index m? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: If I am allowed to replace $a_{ij}$ with the coordinate functional $f_i^*$ of $W$ wrt its basis $\mathcal{F}$, then I have the linear combination $\tau=\sum_i\sum_j f_j^*[\tau(e_i)] \cdot f_j \cdot e_i^*$. Compare this to the case when $W=\mathbb{R}$, it seems that, for $\tau\in\hom(V,\mathbb{R})$, we have implicitly chosen the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e., $(1)$, thus the coordinate functional for $(1)$ is an identity function, thus we have a simplified version for $\tau\in\hom(V,\mathbb{R})$, that $\tau=\sum_i\tau(e_i) \cdot e_i^*$. So everything is consistent...Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, think it twice, I was wrong to assume that *we have implicitly chosen the basis $(1)$ for $\mathbb{R}$*: it seems that any basis for $\mathbb{R}$ have the same result, $(1)$ is just the simplest.